# Using cross-join / pivot with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, pivot, cartesian-product

I have a collection with the following structure.

```
List<QuestionAnswer> answers = new List<QuestionAnswer>(){};

class QuestionAnswer
{
  string Question { get; set; }
  string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

It is populated with the following data:

```
Question Answer
Q1       a
Q1       b
Q2       c
Q2       d
Q2       e
```

I need to convert it to the following format:

```
Q1   Q2
 a   c
 a   d
 a   e
 b   c
 b   d
 b   e
```

The Questions are not known until run-time; there may be n number of Questions in the collection. I believe I need to CROSS JOIN the collection on itself and somehow display questions as headers (pivot rows and columns). I was not able to produce the target data format. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<QuestionAnswer> answers = new List<QuestionAnswer>() { 
                new QuestionAnswer() { Question = "Q1", Answer = "a"},
                new QuestionAnswer() { Question = "Q1", Answer = "b"},
                new QuestionAnswer() { Question = "Q2", Answer = "c"},
                new QuestionAnswer() { Question = "Q2", Answer = "d"},
                new QuestionAnswer() { Question = "Q2", Answer = "e"},
            };

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            List<string> uniqueQuestions = answers.Select(x => x.Question).Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (string question in uniqueQuestions)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(question, typeof(string));
            }

            var groups = answers.GroupBy(x => x.Answer).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                foreach (QuestionAnswer qA in group)
                {
                    newRow[qA.Question] = qA.Answer;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    public class QuestionAnswer
    {
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Gives following :
[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution. While it does not output the data as described, it gives a good insight, thus deserves an up vote.

Comment: The input didn't map to your output so I did the best I could.